# Node Server With NGINX

Tags: javascript, node.js, nginx

I have node js server that has a server which listens 8000 port and a socket.io connection working on that server. This socket connection creates a communication with a ReactJS app which is not a point of this question. So I have 2 project folders

```
1. project-server 
2. project-web-react
```

Project server only answers socketio request and does not render a HTML or something else. It only works on terminal. I want to ask whether is it useful to encapsulate my project-server with Nginx? So the requests are handled by Nginx ? Or is it out of the Nginx's purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would never have an application server run directly connected through internet since there are always a bunch of unknowns with them (scaling, standard compliance etc), so I would recommend you to run a proxy like nginx in front of your app. This also makes it easy to add certificates and do load balancing / caching. It just adds flexibility and some security.

Comment: I understand the drawbacks, thank you, that answers my conceptual question.